# android: approaches for displaying errors

Tags: android

Is there a recommended "Android way" of displaying errors to the user?

For example, suppose I catch an exception in my Application/Service and the user needs to be informed about it - is the usual approach to display a toast/pop-up dialog if the application is being displayed and a notification in the notification bar if the application is in the background?

Comment: I wouldn't use `Toast` as it is possible the user may be briefly distracted from the screen and they won't see it. If there is an error the user needs to be notified of then use `AlertDialog` with buttons for options on how the user would like to handle the error.

Comment: @Sqonk - thanks, what if my application is not currently in the foreground (i.e. the error occurred in an accompanying Service)? Do I still use an AlertDialog?.

Comment: If you have no visible `Activity` then it is even more likely that the user won't be watching the screen for you to show an error `Toast`from the `Service` (they may not even know the `Service` is running). In this case, I disagree with Vinay S Shenoy and would say you should use a `Notification` which can trigger an `Activity` with an `AlertDialog`. It does really depend on what your app does though and also what the user can do to rectify the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the type of error, of course. But never show an error in the notification bar.

As a general rule, try to gracefully continue app execution, without informing the user.

If the error is such that your app cannot continue with what the user asked it to do no matter what, show a Toast.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments in my reply, you can show an AlertDialog or a Toast depending on the severity of the error.

In my opinion, however, using a notification to show an error message is only applicable for very specific use cases as in downloaders or music players where the app is performing a user created task in the background.

Comment: **"never show an error in the notification bar."** - I disagree. For example, I use an `IntentService` to perform daily downloads of data and it creates an 'ongoing' `Notification` to show progress similar to when Google Play updates an app. At the end of the download, the `Notification` is changed to show 'Download complete'. If something fails, however, such as lack of network connection, the `Notification` shows 'Download failed' and when the user taps on it, it opens an `Activity` allowing the user to 'Try again'.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't think of that. But this is appropriate only in certain use cases, where the action is happening in the background WHILE the app is paused. In cases where the user is interacting with the app, it's better to show a Toast...

Comment: I agree that it depends on the situation BUT I still think it is easy for a user to be distracted from the screen and a `Toast` is short-lived and they might miss it. I think an `AlertDialog` would be better if they are interacting with the app. See my comment on the OP's question.

Comment: Whether to use AlertDialogs are Toast depends on the severity, IMO... I'll have to update my answer with that.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to give any custom message of yours then you are answering itself in your question which can be done through using Toast.

```
try {
///stuffs
} catch(IOException ioe) {
Toast.makeT......
}
```

Comment: Can you display a toast from a Service - what context would I use?

Comment: @Mewzer for displaying text from service use on handler in activity and pass this to service, from service you can use sendMessage(msg) which will fire handleMessage(...) of handler there you can display toast.